# How can Google Maps markers be used in objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, object, google-maps-markers

I have an array "markerGroups" defined like this:

```
var markerGroups = {"foo": [], "bar": [], "foobar": []};
```

This array is used for storing all the markers in a Google Map. As you can see, I have three categories where I store the markers. One marker will only exist in one category, and will never exist in any other category.
Each marker is also identyfied by a unique ID, for instance the ID can be 1422.

Now I want to add the markers to this group in such a way that i can reach it by doing for instance

```
console.log(markerGroups.foo[1422]);
```

Even if that's the only marker in that category. I must also be able to remove it completly from the category.

I have tried to make this possible by defining markerGroups like this:

```
var markerGroups = {"foo": {}, "bar": {}, "foobar": {}};
```

This line is in a function where the marker is defined as marker, and category is passed into the function, telling the function where to store the marker.

```
markerGroups[category][marker.ID] = marker;
```

This works excellent, except the fact that markers now won't show up in my map.

Any ideas why or how this could be done in a better way?

Comment: You haven't provided enough details to tell why `markerGroups[category][marker.ID] = marker;` won't show up on the map.  There isn't anything about that difference that should stop it from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markers are simple JS objects that can be manipulated in the same way that any JS object can.

The only way you can control if a Marker is shown on the map is via it's setMap() function. So check out your code and see if you call setMap(your_map) for the markers you want to be shown on the map. Also bear in mind that there are some properties that must be set (position for example) in order the Marker to be shown.

So, don't worry of simple JS object manipulation, it doesn't interact with the Marker visibility, as long as it's initialized properly.

Of course, this is a theoretical point of view, if you've done all this and it still doesn't work, you must provide some additional details and code.

Comment: I left out that I have a markerclusterer (wich actually was the problem here), because I thought the problem was related to me trying to use objects in stead of "clean" arrays.
Your answer lead me into the right direction, and also made me confident that objects should work just fine.

Thanks!